# Weird needle like crystals formed in galvanic cell after drying

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

So I set up a series of galvanic cells for fun; had a brass nut in a glass container and a chunk of zinc in another. I immersed the brass nut and zinc in a solution of saltwater, and connected them with a saltwater-soaked paper towel.

When the side with the brass dried out, a bunch of salt crystals, as well as blue copper carbonate formed. However, a bunch of long, white, needle-like crystals also formed. What could these be?

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000 words. Share a photo if possible.

Comment: What is the meaning of the words "when the side with the brass dried out ? Does it mean, that you had waited long enough to let both solutions evaporated ? During this time, did the cell function, and deliver enough currant to be discharged ? Did you see the salt crystals, the copper carbonate and the long needle-like crystals on the same electrode ?